# Defining constants in include file in php 5.6

Tags: php, include, constants

Here is a code bellow which is fine in PHP<5.6 but I can't get it to work properly since migrating the script in PHP5.6.

myscript.php :

```
define('FOO','hello');
include('somefile.php');
echo ANOTHER_FOO;
```

somefile.php :

```
define('FOO','hi');
define('ANOTHER_FOO',FOO.' world');
```

myscript.php prints :

- in PHP<5.6 : "hello world"
- in PHP5.6 : "hi world"

The result expected is "hello world". How can FOO be redefined ?
I know that FOO should not be redefined in somefile.php but that's not really the point here I'm just trying to understand why it happends.

Thanks !

edit :

```
define('FOO','hello');
define('FOO','hi');
define('ANOTHER_FOO',FOO.' world');
echo ANOTHER_FOO;
```

That works fine, the problem is only with an inclusion.

edit :

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68765

It seems to be a known bug with opcache and php 5.6 :

- PHP 5.6.6 and opcache disabled : "hello world"
- PHP 5.6.6 and opcache enabled: "hi world"
- PHP 5.5.22 and opcache disabled : "hello world"
- PHP 5.5.22 and opcache enabled : "hello world"

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://3v4l.org/vhPO3

Comment: ^ -> Add error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` and you will see it

Comment: The second definition of FOO must be in an included file.

Comment: @shacreaw Doesn't makes a different!

Comment: Rizier123, the notice says that ANOTHER_FOO is already defined in the included file but why since the inclusion is after the first declaration ?

Comment: I've just installed PHP 5.6 just for you, and I *still* cannot reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @deceze i may not be the only one with this problem : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68765

Comment: So, an opcache related problem? That seems more likely. You may want to post that below as a pointer for future reference, but there's not much constructive help we can offer on SO in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Meantime adding a touch to invalidate the cache do the trick :

```
define('FOO','hello');
touch('somefile.php');
include('somefile.php');
echo ANOTHER_FOO;
```